# Python Stripe source successfully created but 'No such token' for sepa_debit

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am using stripe with python. I followed [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/iban) to create a sepa_debit source object.

As far as I understand I need to create a source object before I can create a charge, because the charge needs the source object ID.

I dont care about customers at this point as all charges should be one-time and the source objects not reusable.

Well to make it short, on the client I get a positive response from stripe and a src_id:

[image]

This is a successfull response or am I wrong? It happens in this part:

```
// Call `stripe.createSource` with the iban Element and additional options.
stripe.createSource(iban, sourceData).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
        // Inform the customer that there was an error.
        errorMessage.textContent = result.error.message;
        $('#error-message').removeClass('display-none');
        $('#book-room-container #book-room-form button[type="submit"]').text("Unterkunft kostenpflichtig buchen");
        $('#book-room-container #book-room-form button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", false);
        //stopLoading();
    } else {
        // Send the Source to your server to create a charge.
        $('#error-message').addClass('display-none');
        console.log(result.source); // <-- THIS IS THE LOG OF THE IMAGE ABOVE
        console.log(result.source.id);
        console.log(result.source.type);
        $('#book-room-container #stripe_source_id').val(result.source.id);
        $('#book-room-container #stripe_source_type').val(result.source.type);

        // create charge and return charge id
        $.ajax({
            url : '/process-stripe-payment',
            type : "post",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            data : JSON.stringify({'total_price': total_room_price, 'user_email': $.trim($('#book-room-container #sepa_email').val()), 
                'room_id': $('#book-room-container').data('roomid'), 'sepa_owner': $.trim($('#book-room-container #sepa_owner').val()),
                'stripe_source_id': $.trim($('#book-room-container #stripe_source_id').val()), 'stripe_source_type': $.trim($('#book-room-container #stripe_source_type').val())}),
            success : function(response) {
                console.log("process-stripe-payment", response);
            },
            error : function(xhr) {
                console.log("failed process-stripe-payment", xhr);
            }
        });         
    }
```

I am a bit suspicious because to create this source object the public key was enough, but that is what the documentation tells. Their hint also tells that now I should be able to use the src_id and create a charge:

> // Send the Source to your server to create a charge.

Now I am taking the src_id and some necessery data and go to the server, where I want to create the charge:

```
// create charge and return charge id
$.ajax({
    url : '/process-stripe-payment',
    type : "post",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data : JSON.stringify({'total_price': total_room_price, 'user_email': $.trim($('#book-room-container #sepa_email').val()), 
        'room_id': $('#book-room-container').data('roomid'), 'sepa_owner': $.trim($('#book-room-container #sepa_owner').val()),
        'stripe_source_id': $.trim($('#book-room-container #stripe_source_id').val()), 'stripe_source_type': $.trim($('#book-room-container #stripe_source_type').val())}),
    success : function(response) {
        console.log("process-stripe-payment", response);
    },
    error : function(xhr) {
        console.log("failed process-stripe-payment", xhr);
    }
});
```

Here is the server code:

```
@app.route('/process-stripe-payment', methods=["POST"])
def process_stripe_payment():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data_received = json.loads(request.data)

        print (data_received, data_received['stripe_source_id'])
        # FIRST TRY STRIPE

        stripe_charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=int(float(data_received['total_price']) * 100),
            currency="eur",
            source=data_received['stripe_source_id'],
            description=None,
            #customer=user_id, # None if guest
            capture=False, # if False the charge needs to be captured, otherwise it will expire in 7 days and is refunded
            #receipt_email='email für den typer, der die rechnung kriegt, funktioniert nur im livemode',
            metadata={
                'user_email': data_received['user_email'],
                'room_id': data_received['room_id']
            }
        )
        print (stripe_charge)

        return json.dumps({'status' : 'success'})
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The problem is that it does not work. In the stripe logs I see that a request was made but failed (`400`). The error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such token: src_1DCRd12eZvKYlo2ClWoO3vFj",
    "param": "source",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the publishable key and the secret key you're using match? That error usually means that you created the source using one account's publishable key and then tried to make the charge with another account's secret key.

Specifically, this can happen really easily if you copy the examples from Stripe' site — these have example keys which work, but they are not your *own account's keys* so that could be why you get the error. Make sure you're using your publishable key from https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys .